# Deleted a table, created it again, now it doesn't appear in the dbo

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Management Studio, I deleted a table, and created it again using a SQL query. Now in code I cannot call it using dbo. something something. It just doesn't appear in the intellisense.

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Edit: I can't delete the table again and RE create it with [dbo] tag. Any other solutions?

Comment: Did you refresh the intellisense in the mean time?? Does the table show up in the Object Explorer??

Comment: Run: `SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name LIKE '%your_table%'` and tell us what the `table_schema` value is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER MyName.MyTableName
```

[reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mosharaf/archive/2007/02/21/how-to-move-objects-from-schema-to-another-in-sql-2005.aspx)